# child table data structure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm working on my database tables I've different tables but there are two main tables one is `module_names` and second is `allowed_modules` now in `module_name` is parent and `allowed_modules` is child table.

**module_names**

```
-------------------------------------------------
id, module_names, module_status

1  Insert        1
2  Delete        1

-------------------------------------------------
```

**allowed_modules**

```
-------------------------------------------------
id, user_id, module_id

1   1        1
2   1        2

-------------------------------------------------
```

now in my child table there is column `module_id` where module ids are inserted along with user id which means that user has allowed these modules, now in child table there is duplication of user id its ok I've done projects before like this but now when I discuss with my colleague and show him these two tables he suggest me that don't insert duplicate user id with module id just change the column type from `int` to `text` and insert data in allowed modules in `json encode` format I told him that's child table but he told me it not better approach because every time if you get modules you've to execute loop but if its in `json encode` format you don't have to execute loop every time.

So what is the better approach store ids individually or just encode data in json format, because I don't want my database operations heavy like `fetching` from multiple tables or other operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json type is ok only if you don't want to search for records in future.
for example if I asked you that how many users has rights to access module_id =2 ?
or if I asked you that how many modules user_id = 1 has allowed?
you will never achieve such kind of requirements in json case.

my recommendation is if you are worry about duplicates. make user_id and module_id columns unique in that case there 'll be no duplicates for same user

```
ALTER TABLE allowed_modules
ADD UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_key` (`user_id`, `module_id`)
```

Comment: child table always have duplication, I know user_id and module_id can't be unique...

Comment: you mean user_id = 1 has module_id = 1, and then same record again exist multiple times??

Comment: no no  I mean if `user_id=1` has allowed two modules like `module=1` and `module=2`.

Comment: then I think you are good to go.
where as the only disadvantage of using json is already mentioned above in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your DB model looks good with respect to relational model. Joining just 2 tables will not be performance inefficient.

JSON column will be good if this is more read intensive application. But this will increase the storage as you need to store the Module name in JSON to avoid join.

Answer (score 0):

I think thtat it depends on where your app strenght lives, I mean, if you guys have a strong database or a strong processing app, I would leave that payload to the database ( your duplicated user id approach ) because as a SQL sentence it can be processed fast even when you have too many users with too many modules, you could use hints and indexes for to make your querys faster, and at some point going with strings ( long json ) can get complicated, but as I started this comment, it depends on how you guys decide your app's logic to be strong DB or programing lang.